# knockout.js: where to save the viewmodel if AJAX call is in usercontrol

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am struggling to understand where do i keep viewmodel while user is on the page. I have several usercontrols that make the AJAX request and apply binging to controls in the usercontrol. I am using mapping plugin to populate my viewmodel. I have 4-5 usercontrols on the page. I am struggling to keep the viewmodels in memory so that it can detect the changes and send back to server. As of now i am saving them in window.Model1 property which is not a good idea.

Can someone please tell me what is the best way to keep viewmodels in memory so that i can detect changes? Or is it that i am doing it toally wrong and there is a better way to handle this kind of scenario.

Here is the code for all of it.

UserControl:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ucCustomer.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.UserControl.ucCustomer" %>

<input data-bind="value: FirstName" /><br />
<span>FirstName: </span><span data-bind="text: FirstName"></span><br />
<input data-bind="value: FirstName" /><br />
<span>FirstName: </span><span data-bind="text: LastName"></span><br />

<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ws/GetData.asmx/GetCustomer",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: handleHtml,
        error: ajaxFailed
    });


    function handleHtml(data, status) {

        var myViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.d);
        window.myViewModel = myViewModel;



        ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
    }

    function ajaxFailed(xmlRequest) {
        alert(xmlRequest.status + ' \n\r ' +
              xmlRequest.statusText + '\n\r' +
              xmlRequest.responseText);
    }

</script>
```

Aspx Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2._Default" %>

<%@ Register Src="UserControl/ucCustomer.ascx" TagName="ucCustomer" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SendDataBackToServer() {
            var arrayList = new ArrayList();
            arraylist[0] = window.myViewModel;
            arraylist[1] = window.myViewModel1;
            arraylist[2] = window.myViewModel2;

            //Make an AJAX call here and send arrayList back to server
            return false;
        }

    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <div id="dvCust">
        <uc1:ucCustomer ID="ucCustomer1" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <button title="Send Data Back" onclick="JavaScript: return SendDataBackToServer();">
            Send Data Back To Server</button>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Web Service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using WebApplication2.DataModel;

namespace WebApplication2.WS
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for GetData
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class GetData : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public Customer GetCustomer()
        {
            return new Customer
            {
                FirstName = "FName",
                LastName = "LName"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Customer Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication2.DataModel
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this article, it helped me a lot :)
[Using knockout with asp.net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153735/Using-KnockoutJS-in-your-ASP-NET-applications)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your app works.  It appears your only using knockout for secondary tasks, not a primary function of the app. I think using a global namespace is probably the best solution.

If you create a variable outside a function body, then that variable is in the global scope.  So choose a namespace `var myknockoutnamespace = {}` then place whatever structure you need into that (multiple view models, static classes, Konkani code implementations,etc...)

I know this is high level, but the answer really is that simple.  There's really nothing wrong with using the global scope as long as you keep all your work within your own unique namespace.

Another reasonable solution would be the [jQuery .data() method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/).  With it, you can associate data with a DOM node.  Each of your user controls could own a Dom node that doesn't even need to be visible, or, it could be the node that you bind to your view model (maybe, never tried that myself).  Leaving the page or deleting the Dom element effectively deletes your namespace/view model.  This keeps the data inside the DOM and out of the global namespace.  You can call up the variable anywhere by using the nodes selector.  `$('#myusercontrolcontainer').data() //returns whatever data us associated to that dom node.`

jQuery, uses this extensively throughout plugins and jQueryUI as its data storage method.

Hope is helps.  Happy Coding

Comment: what do you mean by using knockout for secondary tasks? isnt it a primary task of KO to bind data to elements and track changes?

Comment: I was assuming, based on your example that you are delivering small pieces of your apps functionality via knockout.  since you are running Ajax statements as soon as the page is rendered and it's not immediately apparent of any way to update that data later.   I was actually wondering why you chose to do it this way.   If the data is knowable at the point of loading the user control, why not just use asp.NET to deliver that content as well?

Comment: To be clear, whether you are writing a 100% knockoutJS app or just adding small functionality to your app, the answer above still applies I think.  I am writing a full app using a global var as my namespace.  Every view model, view, controller, etc... All live inside that one POJO.